# Ionic: get ionicScroll onScroll event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I found this thread that tells how to get the scroll event of a ionicScroll:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicscrolldelegate-doesnt-have-a-onscroll-event/19497

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().onScroll = function () {
    console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition());
};
```

But this doesn't work. The official doc doesn't have anything about this. Any clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you simply want to listen to to the scroll event maybe the easiest way would be to use the `on-scroll` directive.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-content on-scroll="getScrollPosition()">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in data.items">Item {{item}}</div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.getScrollPosition = function(){
   console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top)
}
```

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJLzGb)

Comment: For some reason, this code does not work in my app. I think I have something else "blocking" it. I found a blog post which tells to use the on-refresh directive to call a function that broadcast scroll.refreshComplete event (with $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');) and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: How to approach this problem if I want to listen to scroll event from a directive? any help?